# Transfer a file from second machine to third machine

Tags: networking, ftp-client, tftp

I have a three server in a same network. I want to write one application in server1 that transfer file from server2 to server3. That means it create a session between server2 and server3 and transfer a file. Is it possible without adding any service(RPC Service) on server2 and server3.

Answer (score 0):

2 approaches.

1) app XXX running on Server 3 can map/access files on both Server1 and Server 2 performing the transfer. In this case the transfer is S1<->S3<->S2

2) app YYY running on Server 1 can map/access files on Server 2 performing the transfer. app YYY can be remote controlled from Server 3. In this case the transfer is S1<->S2 while the remote control session is S1<-S3

Comment: I will create one service on server1 and invoke this service by server3.